# MapView onCreate throws NullPointerException on LG devices

Tags: android, google-maps

First of all, this problem is for me only reproducible on LG devices (LG G4 and G5) running Android 6. The problem was introduced through the last update of the google play services. If I manually downgrade the google play services on my LG devices the error is gone. Unfortunately I cannot tell my users to do this, so I need to find another solution. As this error is reproducible with my app in the play store I can be certain the error was not introduced through my own code changes.

The error occurs through calling the onCreate() method inside MapView. I subclassed MapView and have my own class like this

```
public class MyMap extends MapView implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    ...
}
```

Inside the constructor of MyMap I call the onCreate method

```
public MyMap() {
    ...
    this.onCreate(null);
    this.onResume();
    this.getMapAsync(this);
    ...
}
```

On my LG devices running Android 6 this throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.aq.e()' on a null object reference
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.ah.getResources(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:340)
at android.util.ResolutionOverride.<init>(ResolutionOverride.java:56)
at android.view.SurfaceView.init(SurfaceView.java:207)
at android.view.SurfaceView.<init>(SurfaceView.java:187)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.am.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:1)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.ah.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:3)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.am.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:53)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.am.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:49)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bv.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:38)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:80)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:1)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cw.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:18)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.t.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:17)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapViewDelegate$zza$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$3.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zzJy(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
```

I found a similar problem with Airbnb's react native map, but their solution does not seem relevant to my problem.
https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/1358

Any help or other ideas I could try out are much appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to update google map in your device this cause the exception.
OR Try to change the lower version dependency of google map in your project.

Comment: Google maps is on its newest version. I already updated the min- and targetSdkVersions from 19->24 to 21->25 and updated the google maps dependencies to 11.0.+ (com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps, etc.). Unfortunately the error still persists.

Comment: Don't need to change min or target Sdk version. You just change the dependencies of google map. Never used + dependencies because it will always fetch the new version if it is available so try to add static version.Try this version 10.2.1 and check it out.

Comment: We were on 10.2.+ before updating to 11.0.+. I now set it fix to 10.2.1 but it's still the same error.

Comment: As I see in your code you extends MapView which is deprecated Try FragmentActivity instead of it. can post your layout.xml where you declare the google map.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper - can you show me that MapView is deprecated ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use MapFragment instead of MapView because for updated google play services 11.0.55 not supporting MapView.  I used MapView its worked for me.

### Activity class:

```
    private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment; 

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_direction, container, false);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_direction, null, false);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mMapFragment = mapFragment;
        return view;
    }

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
mMapFragment.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

### Xml class:

```
<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_lay"
    android:apiKey="@string/google_map_key"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
</fragment>
```

Comment: We are not aware that MapView is not supported anymore. Do you have any official statements for that? Will try out your solution and report back.

Comment: I have my doubts that MapView will be deprecated - I would bet against it.

Comment: @Dika As the problem only affects one or two users, we decided it is not worth the effort. Also https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps still uses MapView and does not experience this problem, so it does not seem related to the usage of MapView

Comment: You can always get the View that holds the GoogleMap from Fragment.getView() and do with it what you would a MapView.