# MapView OnCreate Throws NullPointerException On LG Devices #2

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, android-mapview, lg

My customers (app users) are experiencing the same issue as described in [MapView onCreate throws NullPointerException on LG devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623970/mapview-oncreate-throws-nullpointerexception-on-lg-devices), after calling getMapAsync in the OnViewCreated method of a fragment. The same crash happens with getMapAsync called in the onCreate method.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.ah.getResources (ah.java:340)
  at android.util.ResolutionOverride.<init> (ResolutionOverride.java:56)
  at android.view.SurfaceView.init (SurfaceView.java:207)
  at android.view.SurfaceView.<init> (SurfaceView.java:187)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.am.<init> (am.java:1)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.ah.<init> (ah.java:3)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.am.<init> (am.java:53)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.am.a (am.java:49)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bv.a (bv.java:38)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az.a (az.java:80)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az.a (az.java:1)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cw.a (cw.java:18)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.t.onTransact (t.java:17)
  at android.os.Binder.transact (Binder.java:387)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapViewDelegate$zza$zza.getMap (IMapViewDelegate.java)
```

These are the models reporting the crash,
on Android 6:

- V10 (pplus)
- YT3-X50F/Yoga3 Tablet (YT3-X50F)
- LG G Stylo (g4stylusn)
- LG G4 Stylus (mp1s3gds)
- Sol (idol3)
- LG G4 (p1)
- LG Magna (my90ds)

on Android 5.1:

- LG K4 LTE (me1)
- Spree (e1q)
- V10 (pplus)

Most of them are LG models.

Google Play services version used in the app:
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6

Due to rendering issues, my app by default turns off hardware acceleration. As I have none of those devices myself I would kindly ask someone with one of the above device models to install KinsMap https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.haraluna.rootsmap and do as follows:

1. Try out a map related function by opening the example project and click the map icon on the top, then check if there is a crash.
2. Turn on hardware acceleration in the settings menu and check if the issue is gone.

For your reference, there is also a Google issue on a similar case, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827842.

Please report any findings here.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get hold of a Yoga3 tablet myself, and I can confirm that the issue is solved by enabling hardware acceleration.

As mentioned in the question, this is the side effect that the text gets more blurry (than with software rendering).